# Cocos2d: Invert a texture, display the mirror image?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, texture2d

How could I invert a Texture created from an image (I mean display the mirror image), if I have for example a kid rising his left hand I'll get a kid rising his right hand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
aSprite.flipX = YES;
```

Comment: Now please mark your answer as "answer" so that in the overview people see that this case is closed, or delete it altogether if you feel it's not worth keeping in the archive.

Comment: I could mark it as an answer in two days :) maybe I'll delete it.